# Access Violation error in Laravel-4 migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-4

I have migrations as follows:

**create_users_table.php**

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 255);
            $table->string('username', 64)->unique();
            $table->string('email', 255)->unique();
            $table->string('password',64);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

**create_predictions_table.php**

```
class CreatePredictionsTable extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('predictions', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('fixture_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('fixture_id')->references('id')->on('fixtures');
        $table->integer('home_team_score_prediction');
        $table->integer('away_team_score_prediction');
        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('predictions');
    }
}
```

**create_fixtures_table.php**

```
class CreateFixturesTable extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('fixtures', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('home_team_id');
            $table->integer('away_team_id');
            $table->dateTime('date');
            $table->string('venue');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('fixtures');
    }
}
```

Initially when I ran the migration using

```
 php artisan migrate
```

I hadn't added foreign key's. I ran

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

after adding the foreign key constraints which gave me following errror:

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'predictions' already exists (SQL: create table `predictions` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` int unsigned not null, `fixture_id` int
  unsigned not null, `home_team_score_prediction` int not null, `away_team_score_prediction` int not null, `created_ at` timestamp default 0 not null, `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)
```

I think that is because the table was already there (although refresh is supposed to rollback the migrations and run them again)

When I tried to rollback using

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

I got the following:

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constrain t fails (SQL: drop table `users`)
```

Where am I going wrong? I'm new to migrations, so these might be errors beginners usually get. But I don't understand what exactly I'm doing wrong. I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: What did you change when you added the foreign keys?

Comment: I just added the foreign key constraints in the predictions table `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');` and `$table->foreign('fixture_id')->references('id')->on('fixtures');`

Comment: Okay.. Can you try migrating in this sequence? Users, Fixtures, then Predictions... See if it works. :)

Comment: Even if it works that way, I dont think Its a proper solution. In future If I have another 20 tables it wont be proper to migrate one table at a time, that too in order wherein there tables with FK are created after the reference key tables.

Comment: Well, I think it's because you can't create a foreign key if the table referenced is not yet created.

Comment: Simply delete the table per hand in PMA and then run the migration again.

Comment: Rolling back Laravel Migrations isn't magic.  It simply calls the `down()` function in your Migration file.  Thus, any rules that the actions in your `down()` function break will cause issues with the migration rollback.  In this case, MySQL couldn't drop the table because a foreign key relationship was blocking it.

Comment: Yes, Got it, I have modified down method(s) accordingly based on the dependency on foreign key. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

migration will continue until it meets some problem. So probably a foreign key has already been added, but its associated table is not created yet due to error. If you are trying to rollback, migration will assume that the table associated with a foreign key exists and it will try to rollback that table too.

However, that table does not exist!

Well, the simplest way is to empty the database and rerun migration. I met this problem before and find it hard to rollback step by step once such a problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

**What I Did**
There is a `migrations` table for Laravel.
`Truncate` or empty the table, then delete all tables related to your migrations.
If possible remove any constraints to the foreign keys first before deleting the table.

You should be good to go migrating again.

**Addition**

Take care of the order of deletion of tables in `down()` function.

Deleting some tables with referential constraints as declared by `onDelete()` definitely needs constraints to be removed first.

I think that's causing your rollback error.

Look more into your migrations , buddy :-)